# Why I'm not getting contradiction for $B$?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.

My attempt: Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected. Then we can write $\mathbb{R}= A\bigcup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are non empty  open disjoint set .
Fixed $a \in A$ and $b \in B$

Take $G=\{ x\in \mathbb{R} | [ a, x] \subseteq A\}$.Here $G$ is bounded by $b$  .Now used the completeness axiom  of $\mathbb{R}$ , then $G$ has  upper  bound  call it $c$  .Now we have   $\sup G = c$

Since $ A$ and $B$ cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ , so $c$ must be lie  either in $A$ or $B$

Since  $A$ is open , so there exist  open ball $B_{\epsilon}(c) \subseteq A$.Now for any $y \in B_{\epsilon}(c)$ some $ y$ such that  $c < y <c + \epsilon$  we have  $[a,y] \subseteq A$.
This put $y$ also in $G$ since $B_{\epsilon}(c) \cap G\neq \emptyset$
But here $c+ \epsilon $ is the upper bound so we are getting contradiction that $c$ is suppose to be upper bound .
Therefore $ c\notin A$

Now for $B$

Since  $B$ is open , so there exist  open ball $B_{\epsilon}(c) \subseteq B$.Now for any $y \in B_{\epsilon}(c)$ some $ y$ such that  $c-\epsilon < y <c $  we have  $[a,y] \subseteq A$.
This put $y$ also in $G$ since $B_{\epsilon}(c) \cap G\neq \emptyset$.Here $c$ is the upper bound as same as upper bound of $G$

Therefore $c$ must be lie on $B$

But here I have to contradicts both $A$ and $B$ .

I'm not able to find out my mistake. Where am I doing mistake?

> **My doubt**: why I'm not getting contradiction for $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c-\epsilon<\sup G$, there is some $y\in G$ such that $c-\epsilon<y<c$. Since $y\in G$ you know $[a,y]\subseteq A$. In particular, $y\in A$. But $y\in B_\epsilon(c)\subseteq B$. So $y\in A\cap B$.

Comment: im not getting how  $y \in A \cap B$ give contradiction ?

Comment: Recall the original assumptions. Those sets are disjoint.

Comment: ohh sorry    ..got it @halrankard